# C++ TCP IP Client, send/recv messages overlap?

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, send, recv

I am currently trying to create a C++ TCP IP Client that can send a specific string to a server, which makes the server send back a string with some numbers I need to use.

Specifically I need to send the string "getpos", and only that.

This works perfectly on the first loop, but on the second loop and onward. Whenever I try to send "getpos" again, it will overlap "getpos" with the numbers I previously recieved from the server and send that like:
"getpos20,123,24"

It's like the buffer or something hasn't cleared.
My program works perfectly when connecting to a Python server, but not a C++ server.

I have looked through others with similar issues, and tried various fixes. Nothing has worked so far.

### Here is my current client code (on Linux):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //  Create a socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //  Create a hint structure for the server we're connecting with
    int port = PORTHERE;
    std::string ipAddress = "IPNUMBERHERE";

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    std::cout << "listening" << std::endl;
    //  Connect to the server on the socket
    int connectRes = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connectRes == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
    //  While loop:
    char buf[4096];
    int buflen = 1024;

    while(true){
        //      Send to server

        std::string getmypos = "getpos";
        int sendRes = send(sock, getmypos.c_str(), getmypos.size(), 0);
        if (sendRes == -1){
            std::cout << "Could not send to server! Whoops!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        //      Wait for response
        memset(buf, 0, 4096);
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, buflen, 0);

        if (bytesReceived == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "There was an error getting response from server" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //      Display response
            std::cout << "SERVER> " << std::string(buf, bytesReceived) << std::endl;

            sleep(1);
        }
    } 
    //  Close the socket
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your client code seems fine. What are you doing on the server-side?

Comment: Did you try to run the program in a debugger and step line by line through your code?

Comment: What is your evidence that the 2nd iteration of the loop "send that like: "getpos20,123,24""? Did you sniff network packets and logged the IP traffic's contents, and that's what it is? Can you explain why you believe the problem is with the client code and not the server code.

Comment: _"My program works perfectly when connecting to a Python server, but not a C++ server."_ Then the problem is probably the server?

Comment: Ok, I tried creating a different c++ server, and it works fine. So it is definitely a server side issue with the code from the other server.
I'll look into it and ask further questions about the server code if needed in a new question I think.

Comment: It's better to find the problem if you can show the server code, and the result from tcpdump or wireshark. Without them, it's really hard to solve the problem.